# What attributes are built-in/supported in openGL ES 2.0 Shaders?

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es-2.0, glsl

I am reading a lot about glsl lately and found that some of the attributes that is built in.

Where can I get the information of all the built-in attributes or uniform variables?

Comment: found this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205501/glsl-built-in-attributes-not-accessible-for-iphone-apps?rq=1

I think this is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be what you're after http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/reference_cards/OpenGL-ES-2_0-Reference-card.pdf